In LinearLayout, EditText is only displayed partly. Why?
In my XML I have a linearlayout and a EditText within it. When I compile and run the app, it only displays part of the EditText starting from the left as shown in the picture. It doesn't matter what I place within LinearLayout, it is all the same.
Here is the XML code.
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="374dp"
        android:layout_height="398dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idEdtCourseName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter course Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idEdtCourseDuration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Course Duration"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Course Name"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idEdtCourseTracks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Course Tracks"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Course Track"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idEdtCourseDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Course Description"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Course Description"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/idBtnAddCourse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
            android:text="Add Course"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

I've tried and played with everything I can think off, but it won't change. So, how do you fix this?

the problem seems to be in the width of the LinearLayout! as you have used absolute value, on devices with smaller width, it will clip as in the screenshot you added above. just set width to match_parent and also remove app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0".
